# why am i getting warnings errors due to assignment of a variable's address to a pointer in the global scope?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, scope, warnings

[this the snip of the warning i was getting when i tried to compile the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYYp2.png)I am just getting started with pointers and this following program is being flagged by compiler for some reason I am not able comprehend. the code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int dec = 0;
int *d;
d = &dec;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

there is no error when I am stuffing these declarations in to main's body. the version of gcc I am using is gcc version 12.2.0(downloaded using MSYS2) and code editor MS visual code.can anybody post an explanation for this?

as i have stated above i have randomly started typing a program to get familiar with pointers, i expected there to be no variation in the treatment of pointers regardless of where they are being declared and intialised.

Comment: Please make a habit of avoiding global or file-scope variables. The earlier you stop using global variables the easier it is.

Comment: Also, if you get compiler warnings/errors and want to ask about them please include them in your question.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to perform an assignment outside of a function, which is not allowed.  What you *can* do is initialize:

```
int *d = &dec;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use only declarations in file scopes.

In the provided program you are using an assignment statement

```
d = &dec;
```

in the file scope. So the compiler issues an error.

Instead you could write for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int dec = 0;
int *d = &dec;

int main( void ) {
    return 0;
}
```

As the variable `dec` has static storage duration then the expression `&dec` is an address constant and my be used as an initializer for the variable `d` that also has static storage duration.

From the C Standard (6.7.9 Initialization)

> 4 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
> or thread storage duration **shall be constant expressions or string
> literals**.

and (6.6 Constant expressions)

> 7 More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers.
> Such a constant expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the
> following:
>
> — an arithmetic constant expression,
>
> — a null pointer constant,
>
> — an address constant, or
>
> **— an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an
> integer constant expression.**

and

> 9 **An address constant is** a null pointer, **a pointer to an lvalue
> designating an object of static storage duration**, or a pointer to a
> function designator; **it shall be created explicitly using the unary
> & operator** or an integer constant cast to pointer type, or
> implicitly by the use of an expression of array or function type. The
> array-subscript [] and member-access . and -> operators, the address &
> and indirection * unary operators, and pointer casts may be used in
> the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall
> not be accessed by use of these operators.